# Vite unable to load CSS file located in public directory

Tags: vite

I've got the following project:

```
├── README.md
├── dist
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── checkbox.css
│   │   └── input.css
│   ├── styles.css
│   └── styles.js
├── docs
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.css
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── tailwind.config.js
│   ├── vite.config.js
│   └── yarn.lock
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── checkbox.css
│   │   ├── input.css
│   │   ├── postcss.config.js
│   │   └── tailwind.config.js
│   └── index.js
├── visable.yaml
└── yarn.lock
```

Inside the docs/index.html file I reference two CSS files:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/styles.css" />
```

The main file is loaded, but not the styles.css:
[image]

Here's my vite.config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    open: "index.html",
  },
  publicDir: "dist",
  root: ".",
});
```

Comment: i think you should restructure your directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use relative paths you can't use `/dist` folder. By default, `/dist` acts as the folder holding your entire production build. To better understand this, install `http-server` and run it inside `/dist` folder, after you build. It will serve on local exactly what a web server would, on a domain.

When you `build` the app, it wipes out the contents of `/dist` folder and re-populates it with all the files needed to run the app in production, gathering and minifying required dependencies.

If you want a particular file to be copied verbatim to `/dist` folder when building, without it being parsed at all (it's a basic copy), you have to place it in `/public` folder. You can then reference it in your code by starting the `href` with `/` (for the root of `/public`).

Example: `href="/assets/style.css"` would reference `/public/assets/style.css`.

This works in both `dev` (when serving) and `prod` (in the deployed app).